# Initialising only first n chunks / seconds in video player in flutter

Tags: flutter, caching, http-live-streaming, m3u8, video-player

Is there any way to initialise **only first n seconds/chunks** of the video in flutter's **video_player** package (or any other package)? Remaining chunks to be loaded when video is played.

**Video Format:** `m3u8 (HLS Playlist)`

**Use Case:** Since caching is not directly supported and it's difficult to fetch next videos while using cache mechanism, I am trying to store a list of controllers with n seconds/ chunks cached for next n' videos. The complete video will be loaded when the user reaches the specific position in the video list.

Comment: hie have you solve this problem?

Comment: Hello @Chetan Goyal, did you get solution ?